# Vanguard Account Data Error

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I'm unable to access investment position data when using the Intuit Customer Account Data API. It's critical to get this to work for our customers. Is there anyone at Intuit (or other customers using the API) to help us resolve this? Is it possibly related to this issue identified with Quicken? https://qlc.intuit.com/announcements/777225

Comment: Can you please explain what call you are making and what error response you get?

Comment: Hi @codesalsa - we are making the `getInvestmentPositions` call and the response we get is: `{"status_code"=>"200",
 "result"=>
  {"investment_positions"=>
    {"position"=>
      {"investment_position_id"=>"400034660345",
       "market_value"=>"12345.67",
       "reinvestment_cap_gains"=>"false",
       "reinvestment_dividend"=>"false",
       "inv_security_type"=>"OTHERINFO",
       "other_info"=>{"name"=>"Vanguard Account"}}}}}` We do not receive any stock information for any Vanguard accounts our users have.